# What style of home and type of construction is my home built in 1900 in Georgia, USA?

Tags: exterior, brick, construction, old-house, lath-and-plaster

Just purchased this home this year, it was built in 1900 and is Northwest of Atlanta, GA.  The real estate and hazard insurance companies considered it a "wood frame," but upon trying to hang curtains I easily hit bricks.  The exterior is brick, with the exception of the addition at the rear of the home which was added in the 1980s.  I've measured from the exterior brick through a window to the inside of the plaster wall and it measures about 10-11."  The electrical outlets are near the floor and cut into molding that stretches 9" from the floor and I can't deduce what is around the electrical box.  Please see the pictures and let me know if you can deduce the type of construction or style of the home.

[image]

[image]

[image: House Side]

Comment: Structural brick walls tend to have double wythes. Brick fascia or facade walls tend to have single wythes. Sounds like you've got the double. And your "outlet" link goes to your embedded image.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I just added the picture of the outlet without cover; sorry, I'm new here.

Comment: I'm leaning towards the double-wythe idea myself, but when I searched the topic on this site I read it was uncommon so I was looking for confirmation or other opinions.  Thanks for sharing what you think.  If the additional pictures help or make you change your mind, please let me know.

Comment: Fixed up the image embeds. It's nicer to have them after the text or in line with references to them. Up front we just get smacked with pictures without context...

Comment: You've already confirmed the double wythe. You said you hit brick. And note the occasional triples of brick in your walls with the skinny side of the brick facing outward. These triples are tying the two wythes together into a single structural wall.